# Simulator, app snapshots to easily switch between different app builds?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simctl

How can we setup access to different builds so that they can easily / quickly viewed in the simulator..

We have several builds - production, development and one or more feature branches.

From a development and testing point of view, it would be really useful to be able to quickly see each of these versions of our app.

I'm just wondering if there are any services or some sort of configuration we could employ to make this easier.

I'm thinking one major obsticle might be the app id is always the same, so this would stop of from running the builds / app in the same simulator...

I'm wondering if the app could be bundled locally (perhaps from some kind of snapshot) and a script could copy in app to the simulator ?

I guess this could be some kind of tool which would use use the simulator command line tool and swap app builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, all you need to do is keep a copy of the app and drag and drop it into the simulator

https://medium.com/swift2go/how-transfer-your-app-from-one-xcode-simulator-to-another-f4225da9eb7b